# How to automatically fold html tags?

Tags: key-bindings, folding

If I have this react code:

```
<tag>
..
</tag>
```

and the cursor is on top of `<tag>`, tapping on <kbd>%</kbd> will make the cursor jump to the closing `</tag>`.

I want to create a vim key mapping which folds the contents of `<tag></tag>` when the cursor is on top of `<tag>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `foldmethod` is default (`foldmethod=manual`) than you can:

`zfit`

- `:h zf` -- create fold
- `:h it` -- over "inner tag block" text object

[image: asciicast]

PS

And if you are into "automatic" folding, you can try built-in syntax based html folding as described in `:h html-folding`:

```
The HTML syntax file provides syntax |folding| (see |:syn-fold|) between start
and end tags.  This can be turned on by >

    :let g:html_syntax_folding = 1
    :set foldmethod=syntax
```

[image: asciicast]

Comment: i can't see the keystrokes from the actual recording, and typing `:zfit` when the cursor is ontop of a bracket doesn't do anything

Comment: `zfit` @abbood, have you checked help topics?

Comment: No I haven't, I'll take a look and try again. Thanks for your help Maxim :)

Comment: hey it worked _perfectly_! In fact it makes sense to just go through the commands (ie visual selection, then creating the fold. I also liked how we're creating an inner fold and an outer fold)

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
nnoremap <leader>f v%zf
```

Under the hypothesis that `foldmethod` is `manual`:

```
set foldmethod=manual
```

Comment: it didn't work, i made sure that foldmethod is manual

Comment: When you select some lines and hit `zf` did it fold the lines you have selected? You can replace `<leader>f` by a key combination that is available for you e.g. `<C-s>`.

Comment: Could you tell us what is the `filetype` of your buffer (`:set ft?`)?

Comment: IIRC, using `%` to navigate HTML tags requires `matchit` to have been enabled.

Comment: when i type `:set ft?` I see `recording @j` on the status line

Comment: May be could you hit `q` to stop recording macro `j` and try again (you probably hit `qj` somwhere in your session)